# Bitcoin stuck in old tablet with really old wallet - Can't send out or back up

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, blockchain-wallet-app

I found an old tablet I have and it had some BTC on it.  I got it in 2014 and it has a wallet called 'blockchain' on it which I think is blockchain.info at the time and now blockchain.com

I am trying to send BTC out of it, but I get the following error:

[image]

I assume this is because I am using a really old version of the wallet.  So how else can I get this BTC to my coinbase account?

When I try to backup the wallet it asks me for SD location etc but when I open that location on my computer there is nothing there.

Any help on getting the money off of this android wallet would be really helpful thank you